# Dynamically rewrite URLs upon the user's selection - is it possible?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis7, iis

In my PHP based web application, there's a form that generates a URL according to the user's selection.
The form has 7 different fields, each one of them affects the final URL, none of them is mandatory.

The final URL can be:

> /field1/user_setting_of_field1/field3/user_setting_of_field3/field6/user_setting_of_field6/

or just:

> /field4/user_setting_of_field4

these URLs should be rewritten to-

> /results.php?field1=user_setting_of_field1&field3=user_setting_of_field3&field6=user_setting_of_field6

and:

> /results.php?field4=user_setting_of_field4

Is it possible to create a single rewrite rule that will cover these variations?
I'd hate to create different rewrite rule for every possible scenario, it'll take forever...

I'm currently developing the app on a Windows machine with IIS 7.5, but will eventually deploy it to an Apache server.

Is it possible in both? I currently need to solve it for the IIS environment, and later on for Apache.

Comment: For the Apache side of things, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931 Use the following rewrite rule to forward the entire URL into your script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then inside your `index.php` script, get the 'q' parameter, and split it on slashes. Put the values into a map.

```
$pathmap = ();
if ($_GET["q"]){
    $path = split("/", $_GET["q"]);
    for ($i=0; $i+1<count($path); $i++){
        $pathmap[$path[$i]] = $path[$i+1];
        $i++;
    }
}
```